# Is there such a thing as 'percentage of standard deviation explained'?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

I have been reading about percentage of variance explained.
As nicely put in this blog post variance is hard to visualize and not directly comparable to the mean.
https://assessingpsyche.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/two-visualizations-for-explaining-variance-explained/

So I wonder, since from variance we can calculate standard deviation, can we calculate percentage of standard deviation explained since we can do so for variance? or is this nonsense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percentage of variance can be meaningful because it the regression is it's additive. The percentage of the standard deviation is not going to be additive or linear, which will make this measure difficult to use and understand.

In a typical regression $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$ you have $\sigma^2_y=\sigma^2_{X\beta}+\sigma^2\varepsilon$, so you can re-write it as:
$$1=\frac {\sigma^2_{X\beta}}{ \sigma^2_y}+\frac{\sigma^2_\varepsilon}{\sigma^2_y},$$
where the first term on the right hand side is the percentage of variance explained. This nicely allocated the variance into explained and unexplained components.

You can see that this doesn't work out nicely for the standard deviation:
$$1\ne \frac {\sigma_{X\beta}}{ \sigma_y}+\frac{\sigma_\varepsilon}{\sigma_y},$$
actually you can show that:
$$\frac {\sigma_{X\beta}}{ \sigma_y}+\frac{\sigma_\varepsilon}{\sigma_y}=
\sqrt{1+2\frac {\sigma_{X\beta}}{ \sigma_y}\frac{\sigma_\varepsilon}{\sigma_y}},$$
i.e. the sum of percentages of explained and unexplained standard deviations is greater than 100%. For instance, if only a half of variance is explained, in terms of the standard deviation it **would look** like 71% is explained, but it's misleading, because in this case 71% is unexplained too! Here's the math:
$$\frac {\sigma^2_{X\beta}}{ \sigma^2_y}=\frac{\sigma^2_\varepsilon}{\sigma^2_y}=\frac 1 2$$
$$\frac {\sigma_{X\beta}}{ \sigma_y}=\frac{\sigma_\varepsilon}{\sigma_y}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\approx 0.71$$

Comment: Thanks. In which case, can I ask a related sub-question: once I find the variance explained (by another variable), I am basically 'shrinking' the square of my prediction error (as in the blog animation I pasted above). In other words, once I account for say 90% of variance, I really have to deal with only 10% variance. Does this mean the SD is now smaller? (I guess yes) and does it mean 3 SD will be contained in a narrower space (I also guess yes but would like to check).

Comment: Yes, the total error stays the same, if you explain more of it, then the confidence bounds are going to narrow down. These are all in-sample considerations. You need to look at whether this holds once you go out of sample, i.e. for predictions. For instance, you can overfit to squeeze the error variance, but the forecast error variance may increase.

Comment: Hello again, I slept over your nice answers and have a small add-on question: because SD and variance are linked, is there a formula that sums up how much the SD has shrunk given a certain percentage of variance explained? For example, if I have variance = 9 and explain 5/9 of this, then I'm left with unexplained variance = 4. Can I then conclude that the unexplained part (the variation that's still possible in the distribution) will have SD=2 and hence, by explaining over half (5/9) of variance I shrunk the SD by 1/3 (from 3 to 2)? thanks again

Comment: @matteoeoeo, yes, you can make this statement